# Marriage visitor visa UK

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, weddings

My fiance and I have planned to get married in the UK. He is a UK citizen and I am Indonesian. To apply for a marriage visitor visa, I need to give notice for marriage. But in the requirements of this visa, it says that I need to provide any evidence to show that we really intend to get married, such as booking payment...

He went to the register office and gave them the address of the venue. The staff said that we need to give notice together before booking the wedding. So what documents must we provide for this? I still don't have any clue because they said my fiance couldn't book the venue unless we came together to give notice.

Answer (score 1):

The [guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) S7. Visiting for your marriage or civil partnership , states :

> You should provide evidence that you intend to give notice, marry or form a civil partnership, for example an appointment confirmation with a registrar or booking confirmation for your reception.

So your fiancé needs to make an appointment at the Register Office for a date *after* your intended arrival in the UK for  you to go there together to give notice.

Comment: Yeah the register office advices us to go together. But from my side, i have to apply marriage visitor visa to enter the UK. So, what document i must to provide if they asked to us to give details marriage and show book payment fee, while we cant do that unless go together...this is made me confuse :(((

Comment: @Dhii16 You need to go to the Registry Office together to actually give notice, but you *don’t* need to go together just to make an *appointment* to give notice. You can book a wedding venue eg a hotel, without having given notice.